# Publishing apps built with Experience Builder with ArcGIS developer free subscription

Tags: url, publishing, free-software, arcgis-online-webmap, arcgis-experience-builder

I have built a web experience using my ArcGIS developer free tier account and want to share it when I hit publish it says published successfully but when I share its URL it won't open.

The URL I am using is the one generated by the share widget in the app itself.

I am beginning to think that this is not allowed in developer free tier subscription.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Is the actual Experience and underlying WebMap and Layers all shared "publicly"? This is done in ArcGIS.com, not in the ExB configuration.

Comment: Thanks, publicly sharing in Arcgis com did the job. If I want people to access it without signing in to arcgis online. is that possible on the free tier?

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitations, but they could exist. I don't see any documentation on it more than saying you can only share _data_ with groups. Maybe you could infer that you cannot share with the public on the free tier. I dont know.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will update if I find out about the public sharing without arcgis online login.